# What are some good GUI controls for directx c++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, directx

I need GUI controls that is simple to initialize.

Comment: Can you... be more specific?
Are you looking for a GUI API that supports directx, or are you looking for controls built within  DirectX thatwould be useful to expose to the user in a GUI?
Or something else?

Comment: API, just like edit box, buttons, statics....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the standard WinApi controls on top of DirectX window, at least with OpenGL you can. WS_CHILD on control, WS_CLIPCHILDREN on DirectX Window. Or just use regular window and initialize DirectX scene in sub-window.

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Well.. I already tried that it works if I'm not in full screen mode

Comment: I'm not skilled in DX, but you can create a WS_POPUP window with Rect covering the whole screen. This will lock you to user resolution and bit depth, but depending on task, might be ok. Other than that, I'm afraid you might have to code everything yourself.

Comment: Already tried that too.  The problem is that DX won't let any windows over the actual window.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

"The DirectX Utility Library (DXUT) is a framework used by most of the Direct3D tutorials and samples and is built on top of the Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 10 API."

and...

"DXUT also include a set of textured GUI controls, including an IME-enabled edit box, extra classes such as simple camera types, and a high-resolution timer class. DXUT is designed to be modular, so the application can use all of the DXUT features or just the parts desired."

DXUT has plenty of good UI controls to get you started. All of the code is open for modification as well, so you can copy what you need. The controls are also very easy to initialize. For example, once you have the framework set up, you simply call "AddButton()" and pass in a few parameters.

For a professional project though, I would recommend either writing your own controls or looking at some of the popular frameworks, like [Crazy Eddie's GUI System](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).